# How to solve cuDNN error in the second run of CNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using CNN in keras. After successfully running the model for the first time, the process can not be repeated for second time and the following error appears. In order to solve it, I have to restart my computer each time. May I know how it should be solved?

This is the model:

```
history = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=train_steps,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=valid_steps)
```

This is the warning log:

```
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-414f21bfbe97> in <module>
     22     epochs=epochs,
     23     validation_data=validation_generator,
---> 24     validation_steps=valid_steps)

~\.conda\envs\myenv-36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    817         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    818         workers=workers,
--> 819         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    820 
    821   def evaluate(self,

~\.conda\envs\myenv-36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    340                 mode=ModeKeys.TRAIN,
    341                 training_context=training_context,
--> 342                 total_epochs=epochs)
    343             cbks.make_logs(model, epoch_logs, training_result, ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    344 

~\.conda\envs\myenv-36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in run_one_epoch(model, iterator, execution_function, dataset_size, batch_size, strategy, steps_per_epoch, num_samples, mode, training_context, total_epochs)
    126         step=step, mode=mode, size=current_batch_size) as batch_logs:
    127       try:
--> 128         batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
    129       except (StopIteration, errors.OutOfRangeError):
    130         # TODO(kaftan): File bug about tf function and errors.OutOfRangeError?

~\.conda\envs\myenv-36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py in execution_function(input_fn)
     96     # `numpy` translates Tensors to values in Eager mode.
     97     return nest.map_structure(_non_none_constant_value,
---> 98                               distributed_function(input_fn))
     99 
    100   return execution_function

~\.conda\envs\myenv-36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    566         xla_context.Exit()
    567     else:
--> 568       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    569 
    570     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():

~\.conda\envs\myenv-36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    630         # Lifting succeeded, so variables are initialized and we can run the
    631         # stateless function.
--> 632         return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
    633     else:
    634       canon_args, canon_kwds = \

~\.conda\envs\myenv-36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2361     with self._lock:
   2362       graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 2363     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2364 
   2365   @property

~\.conda\envs\myenv-36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs)
   1609          if isinstance(t, (ops.Tensor,
   1610                            resource_variable_ops.BaseResourceVariable))),
-> 1611         self.captured_inputs)
   1612 
   1613   def _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager=None):

~\.conda\envs\myenv-36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1690       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
   1691       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
-> 1692           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1693     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(
   1694         args,

~\.conda\envs\myenv-36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    543               inputs=args,
    544               attrs=("executor_type", executor_type, "config_proto", config),
--> 545               ctx=ctx)
    546         else:
    547           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(

~\.conda\envs\myenv-36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     65     else:
     66       message = e.message
---> 67     six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
     68   except TypeError as e:
     69     keras_symbolic_tensors = [

~\.conda\envs\myenv-36\lib\site-packages\six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

UnknownError:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[node model/conv2d/Conv2D (defined at <ipython-input-16-414f21bfbe97>:24) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_2996]

Function call stack:
distributed_function
```

---

update:

Python version: 3.6

GPU:NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti

Memory: 16GB

Processor: i7-7700k CPU @4.20Hz

Comment: did you `try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above`?

Comment: Would help to read the error you got.

Comment: @ Lescurel and @Abhishek Rai, please see the question for the warning log message

Comment: This could relate to hardware issue. Please state your environments, Python version, GPU spec, etc...

Comment: @Đinh Anh Vũ, please see the update in the question.

Comment: I solved the problem by doing "Restart Kernel and Clear All Outputs" after each run. can it be a good approach or better alternative can be considered?